# Just downgraded from iOS 11 beta to iOS 10 and now I can't pair my Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos, beta

I'm not sure if my Apple Watch is still running the beta version or what, but I downgraded from iOS 11 beta to iOS 10.3.2 (went to iOS 10.3.3 beta first) and now I can't pair my Apple Watch. I tried to erase all content and settings and when it reboots, it goes into the pairing screen. When I try to pair it, it tells me that my phone needs to be updated.

How do I downgrade the WatchOS beta while running a solid iOS 10.3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t downgrade watchOS, no matter which version of iOS you're running on the paired iPhone. If you want to keep using your iPhone with your WATCH you have the following options:

- Reinstall the corresponding beta version of iOS (11 for watchOS 4, or 10.3.3 for watchOS 3.2.3).
- Wait for the public release of the required version of iOS (10.3.3 should land the week of July 17th).
- Take your WATCH to an Apple Store so they can downgrade it for you. This requires them sending your Watch in for service, which will take a few days.